# HTML page using local data not showing changes to local data immediately

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I am fairly new to web development. I am using HTML and Javascript, specifically the Jexcel Javascript library, to create a spreadsheet webpage. The spread sheet is sourced from a CSV file stored in the working directory of my project. The problem is, when I make changes to that CSV file, they do not show up in my project until I rename the file (and change the filepath in my code respectively). I suspect this has to do with the webpage caching the source CSV file, but I am not sure. How would I go about disabling caching/making my table source from the CSV file everytime? I am using Tomcat Web Server as well. Thank you.

The code that is sourcing my spreadsheet is the following:

```
<script>
    $('#spreadsheet').jexcel({
        allowInsertRow: false,
        allowInsertColumn: false,
        allowDeleteRow: false,
        allowDeleteColumn: false,
        csv : 'data/test.csv',
        csvHeaders : true,
        defaultColWidth : '200px',
    });
</script>
```

When changes are made to test.csv I want those changes to show the next time the page is refreshed, but this is not currently happening.

Update: Restarting the Web Server does make the changes show up, so I believe this is a caching issue. I am using Java Servelets on the Server Side of my code.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue. I never really figured it out aside from either clearing cache and refreshing, or restarting the server all together.

Comment: Javascript is not a very good language to deal with files. You better use same server side.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [ask], the [tour] and how to create a [mcve]: without seeing some code, we can't tell you what code you need to fix :)

Comment: what webserver are you using? You can probably search for how to set no-cache headers on that file using your webserver's settings.

Comment: I have included the javascript code I am using - though I don't think this is a problem with the code itself. I am using Apache Tomcat Web Server.

Comment: Can you use 'Ctrl+F5' combination for force update page?

Comment: did you try this: `csv : 'data/test.csv?v=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)`

Comment: Using Ctrl+F5 does not work. And I have not tried 
    csv : 'data/test.csv?v=' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), what does that do?

Comment: @Sam this will prevent caching

Comment: Whenever I used Tomcat, I ran into this issue, however Atom Live Server has been pretty good. Maybe try that

Answer (score 0):

Browser side caching of resources is a common issue.
To prevent it, the easiest way is to append a version hash to resource url to force reload when modified, so you still benefit of cache feature when file hasn't changed.

Without information about the languages you use on server side, it's very difficult to help you more.
Here is the fonction I generally use to generate resources url :

```
function assetv($path) {
    $hash = 'undefined';

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        $hash = filemtime($path);

        if (!$hash) {
            $hash = md5_file($path);
        }
    }

    return urlFromPath($path) . "?v=" . $hash; 
}
```

*Of course, the "urlFromPath" depends on your app ;-)*

**[EDIT]**

The browser loads your csv file using an url (**data/test.csv**) that is "used as cache key" (approximately).

So to force reload when file was modified, you need to change the url, for instance with a version number parameter (file name doesn't changes) :
**data/test.csv?v=1**
**data/test.csv?v=2**

As server side only is aware of file state, you need to generate the versionned url on server side when building your HTML.

Finally, instead of managing a version number manually, you can use a "natural" attribute of the file, as it's last modification time or a hash of it's content.

Comment: My concern with a solution like this (If I am understanding it properly) is how will the code know the name of the file path after it has been changed and saved differently? I am also using Java for my server side code, I am not very familiar with php. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So the file name doesn't changes. Hash is just a variable in the url.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more how your solution works? Sorry, I'm not familiar with what you're doing in your php code. Also would this solution work if 2 (or more) different users are using the page at the same time?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Hope it's understandable.
Managing concurrent updates on a file is a far more complicated feature.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the suggestions. Ultimately I found out the problem was due to the fact that the csv file I was sourcing my data from was in the project folder and Tomcat does not update changes to that file immediately. I solved this by reading the data from a file stored outside the working directory on my machine.